# EF 4.1 - DBContext SqlQuery and subquery

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, subquery, dbcontext

I want to query the products table by a certain category using EF 4.1. The following is my attempt (which is not working):

```
IList<Product> products = context.Product.Where(pc => this.DbContext.Set<ProductCategory>().Where(oc => oc.Category == 1 || oc.Category == 2).Any(oc => oc.OrderID == pc.ID)).ToList();
```

Can anyone help with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand clearly your model, but you can try something like this:

```
var products = (from p in context.Product
                where p.ProductCategory.Category == 1
                   || p.ProductCategory.Category == 2
                select p).ToList();
```